# How turn data into bar chart?

Tags: python, graph, hierarchical-clustering

I'm struggling with how to turn the result of my code into a bar chart.
Code:
[image: code]
Result:
[image: result]

tried unsuccessfully add data to a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use matplotlib.pyplot and from that import plt. To create a bar chart use plt.bar function.

Comment: Before that, you need to create a list and store silhoutte score, completeness score, homogenity score. You need to call plot.bar three times:
plt.bar(['cosineaverage','manhatten'],silhoutte_score,label='silhoutte')  plt.bar(['cosineaverage','manhatten'],completeness_score,label='completeness')